# Read data from mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

```
db.dimensions.insert({
    "GeoLevels": [{
        "5": "Continent_Name"
    }, {
        "4": "Country_Name"
    }, {
        "3": "Region_Name"
    }, {
        "2": "State_Name"
    }, {
        "1": "City_Name"
    }],
    "AssetLevels": [{
        "2": "Asset_Model"
    }, {
        "1": "Asset_Class"
    }],
    "TimeLevels": [{
        "4": "Year"
    }, {
        "3": "Qtr"
    }, {
        "2": "Month"
    }, {
        "1": "Week"
    }]
})
```

how to read each value of the above this using mongo db and java

Comment: Have you taken a look at mongodb java driver or spring-data mongodb documentation? I guess you'll find your answer in the very beginning of those.

Comment: You've inserted a single document. There are two ways to read this. Either you read the whole document at once, keep it in memory and read from that or you read individual keys on demand. Which option you choose depends on how often the document is changed. The first option would likely be easier.

Comment: I would like to access each and every  element of GeoLevels,TimeLevels,i tried but it didnot work out

Comment: Can you help me in that approach

Comment: @amrutha Could you add the code that you've written - right now I don't understand what the problem is - is it communication with mongodb or processing The results in java?

Comment: Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);DB db = mongo.getDB("test");// Use DB
   DBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
   DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("dimensions");
   DBCursor curs = collection.find();
   Iterator<DBObject> fields = curs.iterator();
     while(fields.hasNext()){
               //DBObject field = (DBObject) fields.next().get("GeoLevels");
               //System.out.println(fields.next());
      ArrayList obj= (ArrayList) fields.next();

       System.out.println(obj);

               

             }

Comment: I am not able to access the elements which are inner

Comment: @amrutha - you should be able to edit your post and add the code there. So much code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
DBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("dimensions");
DBCursor curs = collection.find();
Iterator<DBObject> fields = curs.iterator();
while(fields.hasNext()){
DBObject field = (DBObject) fields.next().get("GeoLevels");
System.out.println(field);
}

Comment: I've copied it to my answer and edited - is it what you were looking for? Does it work for you?

Comment: It is working.Thanks a lot.How to send "5" and get Continent_Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to cast DBObject to one of it's implementation (see all implementations here : https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DBObject.html), in this case BasicDBList, which extends ArrayList , so you can use all methods from arrayList there.

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("test");// Use DB 
DBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject(); 
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("dimensions"); 
DBCursor curs = collection.find(); 
Iterator<DBObject> fields = curs.iterator(); 
while(fields.hasNext()){ //
   BasicDBList geoList = (BasicDBList) fields.next().get("GeoLevels");
   BasicDBObject object = (BasicDBObject) geoList.get(0); // this should return {"5": "Continent_Name"}
   Object value = object.get("5); // value should contain "Continent_Name"
}
```

I also suggest you to look at Spring-data mongodb which allows you to map object from MongoDB directly to POJOs so it is then much easier to work with:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

Comment: ok Thanks you.Suppose if i send "5" How to get Continent_Name in this case

Comment: accepted can u help me in this below scenario                              if i send "5" How to get Continent_Name

Comment: how do i find the values if i give "5"

Comment: it's in the last line